# Why concurrent-ruby exit immediately

Tags: ruby

I am try to use [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) to do some parallel tasks, I am following doc and using `Concurrent::Async`:

```
require 'concurrent'

class Echo
  include Concurrent::Async

  def echo(msg)
    p msg
  end
end

horn = Echo.new
horn.async.echo('one')
```

and run it in terminal , but process is print nothing, and exit immediately

Comment: Did you `require 'concurrent'`?

Comment: @dinjas Would have gotten an error if not.

Comment: @dinjas, absolutely

Comment: I don't know how `Concurrent::Async` works, but just by looking at the code, I see that you fire off an asynchronous method and then *immediately exit* the script. This is an obvious race condition where the thread that runs the asynchronous method races against the main thread that shuts down the interpreter, thus killing all threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'concurrent'

class Echo
  include Concurrent::Async

  def echo(msg)
    p msg
  end
end

horn = Echo.new

# t is an instance of Concurrent::IVar which includes Concurrent::Concern::Obligation
t = horn.async.echo('one')

# wait until obligation is complete or the timeout has been reached
t.wait!
```

[souce code](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/blob/master/lib/concurrent/concern/obligation.rb)